# Jquery iterate input controls in specific order

Tags: jquery

Currently I am iterating over my input control in JQuery

```
 $('#divInputData :input').each(function () { ...do something })
```

I am wondering is there a property that I can use that will allow for me to iterate over each input control in a specific order?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of order? You can use js's function `sort()` at first.

Comment: I want to choose the order it will iterate over my input fields.  If I want it to choose the first field on the page, then skip to the last field, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example of applying javascript's function `sort()` before `.each()`. Order of the elements on the page is not changed, but number after `:` shows in what order `.each` is working. All what you have to do - to decide how do you want to change the order of the elements in array.

```js
    var els = $('div').get().sort(function(el1, el2) {
      return $(el1).text() > $(el2).text();                       
    });
    
    $.each(els, function(ind, el) {
        $(el).append(':' + ind);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div>5</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
```